# Matching geographic time series to known ways

Tags: python, geolocation, computational-geometry

I just started a project where I have a set of path data (given as points with timestamp) and want to match this data to given ways and points from other databases (such as openstreetmap). My task is to determine if a record matches a stored way and to correct for possible distortions in the data. The data size of my record is rather small (a time series of several hundred points), but the database of existing ways is much larger (e.g. the complete openstreetmap database).

As this is the first time that I work with geometric data, I am a bit clueless how to implement this efficiently. I'm sure that there are already algorithms that I could use, but my Google searches so far didn't reveal anything. I want to avoid coming up with complicated solutions to later find out that there are much simpler solutions well known.

What would be an efficient way of solving that problem? I tagged it with Python as this would be my preferred implementation, but I'm open to other languages as well.

Thanks

Comment: question requires to find a book or a tutorial is not valid on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Edit: I changed the question to ask for a more specific problem, I hope that this complies with rules now.

Comment: it is better. thanks for rhe improvment. I vote up.

Answer (score 0):

With the help from another user I found the answer to my question. The topic I was looking for is called map matching, and I found a Github page that gives an overview and some code to work with: 
https://github.com/graphhopper/map-matching

Here's the Wikipedia article for that topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_matching